# What does O2 optimization flag do to the stack frames at compilation in C?

Tags: c, recursion, optimization, stack, frames

What does O2 optimization flag do to the stack frames at compilation? If you had some function that does recursion like this:

```
long long fibb(long long a, long long b, int n) {
    return (--n>0)?(fibb(b, a+b, n)):(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There will not be any recursion in the compiled code. https://godbolt.org/z/7cWGhv

So this optimization in this case will completely remove the recursion.